# get content of RSS Feed article

Tags: java, rss

I would like to get the content off an article from an RSS feed.

For example if you have the CNN RSS feed (http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss). You will get a list of articles. But each article has a content in it.

If you got this article (http://edition.cnn.com/2014/03/23/world/europe/uk-south-africa-dewani/index.html). How can I get the text

> "The Department of Justice and...... carjacking and denies any
>   involvement in the killing."

Is it possible to get the content of the article using the RSS feeds or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: have you seen this nice tutorial? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RSSFeed/article.html

Comment: yes I did see that one. I even used it but it doesn't fill the content String thats why I asked

Comment: then pls show what you've done

Comment: I literally used that code. But I am using the dutch news sites. Maybe that that causes the error?